# Notepad++ How to replace only highlighted text on double click?

Tags: notepad++

I have the following text:

```
/*+ parallel (F ,64)*/          
From  FONTSTAB F
```

If I double click on the letter "F" on the second line, this letter will get highlighted along
with the "F" on the first line.  They both will be highlighted in green.  My question is: how
do I replace these 2 F's with say H?  I don't want the "F" in FONTSTAB to be affected.

I'm using Notepad++ 6.5.4 and haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regex search. You'll just want to replace `\<F\>` with `H`.

Here's how the Regex works, bit by bit:

`\<` - match the start of a word. So a word beginning with F will match this section of the Regex; an F anywhere else in a word will not.
`F` - the character to match. You can replace this with `[FG]` to match one of {F, G}.
`\>` - match the end of a word. So a word ending with F will match this section of the Regex; an F anywhere else in a word will not.

Essentially, we're saying the same F has to be both the beginning and ending character in a word. This boils down to finding a single, freestanding, F character.

I tested the Regex on the following text:

```
/+ parallel (F,64)/
From FONTSTAB F
Formal Fontstab fluff wolf f
```

and it worked correctly. Only the freestanding Fs were found by the search.

Comment: Good.  This works for me.  But how about if I have this:

Comment: Good.  This works for me.  How about if I have this:

Comment: How about this example:

/*+ parallel (F ,64)*/   
From  FONTSTAB F
AND = 'F'

I don't want to affect 'F'.  How do you compose the Regex?

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a good way to do that, given that you want to ignore `'F'` but not `(F,` (in other words, I can't search for an F bounded by special characters). You could try `([^'])\<F\>`, which will match any freestanding F immediately preceded by a `'`, but then you'd have to replace that with `\1H` or you'll lose the first character before the F.

Comment: The sample I've given is a very small excerpt of a GIANT Oracle query in case if you haven't recognized some the SQL keywords.  The F's that I want to replace are those table aliases.  The F surrounnded by the single ticks are the actual database value which I can't affect during search & replace.  I will need to figure out unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: If you want to leave me a bit more of your query to work with (2-3 lines isn't overly helpful if you're planning on applying this Regex to a "GIANT query") I'll be happy to take another look in a few hours. Also, please make sure your anonymization is consistent - if your table alias and database value are two different values, please don't use F for both. ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.  Sorry I won't be able to post the original query in its entirety as it's somewhat sensitive and confidential.  I think if I can figure out how not to affaect the database values, example when the query has something like WHEN GENDER = 'F', then I think I got the exception covered.

Comment: I totally understand not being able to post the original query. But if you can post some anonymized form of it (perhaps replace sensitive table names or w/e with letters, A-Z then AA-ZZ or w/e), or even of a piece of it, I'd be happy to have a look. Or even if you could tell me what surrounds the parts you want replaced - are the ones to leave intact all surrounded by `'`, for example (`'F'`), and the ones to replace are surrounded by something else (`(F,`)? I'm just trying to get a feel for what sort of patterns are in your query so I can form an appropriate Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<!')\bf\b(?!')`
Replace with: `H`

This will replace all `F` that is alone and not preceded nor followed by `'`

`(?<!')` is negative look behind that make sure there is no `'` before the `F`
`(?!')` is a negative look ahead that make sure there is no `'` after the `F`
`\b` is a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

While holding Ctrl, use the mouse to select the pieces of text you want to replace - this can be by double-clicking, or more precisely by click-dragging.

This should select each of your pieces of text simultaneously.

You can then type in the replacement, in this case `H`. You will see a cursor at each place you selected, and can continue typing your replacement as much as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear possible in Notepad++. Select the text Ctrl+H is the fastest, and almost just as fast.. I understand the confusion, it seems odd that an editor would select/highlight all 'like' text and not offer a direct means of replacement without a Find/Replace menu.

Regex..? you guys kill me. He was asking about Notepad++ features.

Comment: How is this answering the question?